# Calendar Entries posted between 11:00pm and 11:59pm show on next day's

Tags: calendar, dst

I've got a channel of events. The main exp:channel:calendar tag displays the entry on the appropriate grid day. When I follow to the date's detail template (/calendar/2013/11/22) the entry that was previously in the grid does not show, and instead shows on the next day (/calendar/2013/11/23).

This only happens if the entry's date/time is posted between 11:00pm and 11:59pm. If I change it to 10:59pm it posts on the correct day just fine.

I know it sounds like a DST type issue. It also could be a server offset issue. I'm still looking into it, but would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely a DST issue. What are your EE date/time settings?

Comment: It definitely was a DST related issue. I was able to change the server offset to fix it for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted in a comment above, this was a DST server setting issue.